# django admin - subquery inside list_filter

Tags: python, django, django-admin, web-development-server, django-admin-filters

Given are the following models

```
class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    confidential = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Owner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    access_granted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the following admin.py from django

```
class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .
    .
    .
    list_filter = ('report__name',)
```

As expected I get the option to filter based on the name of the report. Yet I would like to only get displayed to filter if the report is confidential, means that the `confidential` field of the given report is true. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like to only list the confidential reports in your list_filter. To do this you will need to create a custom filter:

```
class ReportListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'Confidential Reports'
    parameter_name = 'confidential_reports'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        confidential_reports = Report.objects.filter(confidential=True)
        return tuple(
            (report.id, report.name) for report in confidential_reports
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value()
            return queryset.filter(report_id=self.value())
        return queryset.all()
```

To understand the above, you can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), but a summary is that:

- `title`: gives the title for your filter
- `parameter_name`: gives the string that will be used in the URL when your filter is used
- `lookups` returns a list of tuples that gives the values for the filter
- `queryset` is what does the actual filtering.

Then you just need to add it into your `OwnerAdmin` and everything should work:

```
class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .
    .
    .
    list_filter = (ReportListFilter,)
```

Comment: Yes, one report can have several owners. So when I am on the owner table in django admin I would like to have a filter on the right side which displays all reports (name attribute) which are confidential. So i can check which owner(s) have access to which confidential report.

Comment: @ket Great, I believe the above should work in which case :)

Comment: I tried the code posted and got the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'confidential' into field. Choices are: first_name, last_name, title, birth_date, company, address, city, last_login, access_granted, report, report_id`

these fields are the field of the owner model, but not of the report model?

Comment: @ket ah, sorry. I made a typo in my answer, it should have said `report__confidential` not `confidential`. I have corrected it now.

Comment: added the changes now the following error accours
`AttributeError: 'Owner' object has no attribute 'id'`

thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: @ket ah, sorry. It's late for me so I'm not thinking straight. I have corrected the answer again. It should work this time. (make sure you import `Report`)

Comment: It doesnt throw any errors but the filter itself wont work, it now always shows that 0 results for owners have been found?

Comment: @ket ah, we'll get there eventually, where I wrote `report__name` that should have said `report_id`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: works for each individual report now, but why does the all filter return 0 results?

Comment: @ket one last change to hopefully fix that too. (I've just changed the queryset bit)